# Failed to passing InputStream object to Java Sound API

Tags: java, javasound

It works with a `File` object being passed to `AudioSystem#getAudioFileFormat`, but why does it fail with an `InputStream` object below? Any suggestion?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(new File(
                "myaudio.wav"));
        AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(new FileInputStream(
                "myaudio.wav"));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
    at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:330)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(WaveFileReader.java:88)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(AudioSystem.java:985)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

***@EDIT***

According to the answers from `@René Jeschke`, `@Phil Freihofner` and `@Andrew Thompson`, wherever `mark/reset` is required as the mandatory protocal for `Java Sound API` to interact with the `IO stream`, IMHO, the type of `buffered` stream instead of the `raw` one should have been **specially** defined as the signature of the parameter to be passed. Doing so would narrow to the more desirable result than arbitrarily accepting an `IO stream` then resorting to `IOException` as the adverse indicator.

Answer (score 5):

`FileInputStream` does not support mark/reset (for random access), wrap it into a `BufferedInputStream` to get mark/reset support.

Edit: Why is this so? `getAudioFileFormat` iterates through every audio file reader currently registered. Each reader tries to identify the file format by reading some specific bytes. So every reader has to *undo* its changes to the stream (to allow other readers to re-read all data if needed).

When you supply a `File`, that's not a problem because each reader just opens a new stream, but when you pass a stream, each reader must mark the current stream position, do its readings, and reset the stream to its beginning state when it's finished.

That's why you need the `BufferedInputStream` because it adds an in-memory buffer to support mark/reset.

Edit2: Because the question was 'Why does it fail with FileInputStream?' I did not suggest any workarounds, or replacements but tried to explain why it fails when one is using a `FileInputStream`. There are also cases where you can not use URL or the like (consider e.g. a binary package file containing audio files).

Comment: This question has come up multiple times, and probably will continue to do so. The explanation is not bad, but I am dinging it because the proposed "solution" of using BufferedInputStream adds needless work when one can load via a URL and avoid the mark/reset issue altogether.

Comment: As I worked on the question, and got a better understanding of the issues, I realized that the information presented in this answer is quite good, and I was overly critical to give it a -1. I would be happy to give it a +1 to offset my first reaction, but am prevented from doing so, unless your answer gets edited. So sorry! (I'm not sure if I get notified if you edit, but I will be notified if you leave me a note here, and will return to rectify my mistake.)

Comment: I've added a small foot note to my answer. And nevermind, @PhilFreihofner ;-)

Comment: Thanks for note. +1 to correct my -1. Yes, you answered the question which did not ask for workarounds!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (with other Wavs).

```
AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(new File(
            "myaudio.wav").toURI().toURL());
```

The code on the [JavaSound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) also uses an URL.

If what you have is something that is neither a `File` or `URL`, the problem can be fixed by buffering it, as mentioned by René Jeschke, or I generally just read all the `byte[]` and establish a `ByteArrayInputStream`.  That **is** positionable (supports mark/reset).

Answer (score 1):

The AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat() methods call the abstract class "AudioFileReader" in  package javax.sound.sampled.spi.

The comments in the code for the method `AudioFileFormat getAudioFileFormat(InputStream stream) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException;` say that mark/reset may be required:

> ```
>  * Obtains the audio file format of the input stream provided. The stream must
>  * point to valid audio file data. In general, audio file readers may
>  * need to read some data from the stream before determining whether they
>  * support it. These parsers must
>  * be able to mark the stream, read enough data to determine whether they
>  * support the stream, and, if not, reset the stream's read pointer to its original
>  * position. If the input stream does not support this, this method may fail
>  * with an <code>IOException</code>.
> ```

In contrast, the forms `public abstract AudioFileFormat getAudioFileFormat(URL url) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException;`
 and `public abstract AudioFileFormat getAudioFileFormat(File file) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException;`

do NOT make this requirement. The support for the parsers only comes up with the InputStream as a parameter.

The AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream() are similarly commented for the various overloads.

When a mark/reset error comes up in the context of working with Audio Files, the solution to try first is to load the file via its URL and thus avoid the mark/reset requirement (as mentioned by Andrew Thompson). If that doesn't work, sure, use BufferedInputStream, but it shouldn't have to come to that for valid audio files.

The issue is also documented in the Oracle Bug database as bug #7095006.